# Any polynomial of degree greater than $1$ cannot be a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra

True or False. I understand that a unit, is an element which has an inverse. I just can't seem to apply that to a polynomial.

Comment: The answer depends on the ring of coefficients. If that is an integral domain you are expected to apply what you know about the degree of the product of two polynomials.

Comment: And welcome to Math.SE! For your questions to be well received here it is best that you study the FAQ (and also look at highly voted questions for tips). For example, it is best not to rely on the title only for giving the actual question. Also you should give some context. Where did you encounter this problem? If homework, please tell us so (we appreciate honesty here). Tell us what pieces of theory have been covered up to this point. Otherwise the answerers are in the dark as to what kind of an answer you can A) understand, B) benefit from.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you, firstly for your respond. And for the welcome. I am just learning and looking forward to improve. Once again, thanks. By, integral domain, do you mean that it does not have zero-divisors?

Comment: Correct. That is part of the definition of an integral domain.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So, by applying the product, does that imply that the multiplicative identity will be used to identify elements which are units. That is, 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $R$ has no zero divisors then $\deg (pq) = \deg p + \deg q$ in $R[x]$.

Comment: are you implying that deg $p$ + deg $q$ can never be equal to $1$?

Comment: @Ozahm I did not intend to imply that, no.  If $p(x) = 3x + 1$ and $q(x) = 2$, Then $\deg(pq) = \deg p + \deg q = 1$.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I understand that the ring $R$ is an integral domain implying that it has no zero-divisor. I just can't seem to understand how it is linked to the question: The polynomial not being a unit if the degree be greater than $1$.

Comment: @Ozahm "unit" means an inverse.  inverse means they multiply to get $1$, which has degree $0$.  So $0 = \deg(pq) = \deg p + \deg q$...

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, since the degree of the multiplicative inverse 1 is zero ($0$), it implies that the degree of $p$ and $q$, assuming they are integral domains, when added should be equal to $0$, hence the statement is True. @Goos, does the statement imply than that a polynomial of degree $1$ can possibly have a unit?

Answer (score 1):

This is false over the ring $R = {\mathbb Z}_4$ of integers mod $4$. For example $(2x+1)^2 = 1$. So you definitely need to assume that $R$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: That is, that $R$ is an integral domain. Ok